# Remove added SubView

Tags: xcode

i'm tring to remove an added subview but i can't do it...
i add the subView in a UIButton

```
//Create the first status image and the indicator view
UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader_01.png"];
UIImageView *activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                  initWithImage:statusImage];


//Add more images which will be used for the animation
activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader_01.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader_02.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader_03.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader_04.png"],

                                     nil];


//Set the duration of the animation (play with it
//until it looks nice for you)
activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.3;


//Position the activity image view somewhere in
//the middle of your current view
activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                     self.view.frame.size.width/2
                                     -statusImage.size.width/2, 
                                     self.view.frame.size.height/2
                                     -statusImage.size.height/2, 
                                     statusImage.size.width, 
                                     statusImage.size.height);

//Start the animation
[activityImageView startAnimating];


//Add your custom activity indicator to your current view
[self.view addSubview:activityImageView];
```

Now i'd like to remove activityimageView with another IBAction...but Xcode doesn't know that SubView...
Any Idea?!

Comment: place your `UIImageView *activityImageView` in .h file and in IBAction write code like this `[activityImageView removeFromSuperView];`

Comment: As you have got the solution i'm adding my comment as answer.please do accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place your

```
UIImageView *activityImageView
```

in .h file and in IBAction write code like this

```
[activityImageView removeFromSuperView];
```